# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsybctCollect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: unix

How to resolve this error.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsybct
Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I can understand that it says library is missing.

When i searched for that library. It is already installed in my system.

locate libsybct.so
shows me path in which libsybct is installed

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH also shows correct path. I dont know where it went wrong.

There is no symbolic link created for it..

whether creating symbolic link for a library is important... If so where should I create and with what version.

Answer (score 1):

just show the whole command?
maybe you forgot the "-L/your/path" options when you complied.
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH is for running time.
see reference here:  [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lemu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975530/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lemu?rq=1)